# draw a sequence on unimodal map

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw 100 iterates of a unimodal map something like that using tikz. I spend 7 hours trying to do it without success.  Perhaps, some of you already done it  can help me 
thank you.

slim

[image]

Comment: Can you include the equations of motion too. You can't render formulas with TeX code here so the best is to link them somewhere

Comment: this is a link of the math formula (with explanation): http://algo.inria.fr/seminars/sem99-00/moore1.html the mathematical formula is F(x)=4\mu x(1-x),    \mu=0.4

Comment: Suggested title: *How can I draw a [cobweb diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot) in tikz?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pst-plot` was written to solve your problem.

Compile the following `diagram.tex` with either `xelatex` (slower) or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` (faster) to get `diagram.pdf`.

```
% diagram.tex
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\f{-4*x*(x-1)/1.5}
\psset{unit=10}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=1+1}{10}{%
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-.125,-.125)(1.25,1.25)
    \psaxes[linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(-.125,-.125)(1.125,1.125)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{0}{1}{\f}
    \psplot[linecolor=cyan]{-.125}{1}{x}
    \psFixpoint[linecolor=red]{.1}{\f}{\i}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The resulting PDF output (`diagram.pdf`) can then be imported from within your main input (`main.tex`) file as follows.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Animation}
    \animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=1]{10}{diagram}{}{}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Static Image}
    \includegraphics[page=10]{diagram}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Compile the `main.tex` with `pdflatex`. Done!

### Notes for the author of `pst-plot`

`\psFixpoints` should be renamed as `\psFixedPoint` to be consistent with the correct terminology used in mathematics.

Comment: +1 Even thought the OP asked for `tikz` code, I don't think you can produce that kind of plot with such short code in `tikz` out of the box.

Comment: I had a undefined controle sequence line 13 with the code

Comment: thank it works, Is there an english documentation, because I need to add some comments on the picture. The picture is for  slides (with beamer) of my lecture.

Comment: @code Moker: thank you for your help it helps me a lot

Comment: @slim: You are welcome. It is my responsibility to make the OPs get satisfied with my answers. :-)

Answer (score 3):

With PGFPlots. This document compiles directly with `pdflatex` (or `xelatex`, or plain `latex`...)

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={f(\x)=-4*\x*(\x-1)/1.5;}}

\begin{frame}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:1, enlargelimits=false, axis equal image]
       \addplot [thick, black] {f(x)};
       \addplot [thick, black] {x};
       \pgfplotsextra{
       \def\x{0.125}
       \def\y{0}
       \draw [red] (axis cs:\x,\y) \foreach \i in {0,...,20}{
        \pgfextra{
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true, /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
            \pgfmathparse{f(\x)}\xdef\y{\pgfmathresult}
        }
        -- (axis cs:\x,\y) 
        \pgfextra{\xdef\x{\y}}
        -- (axis cs:{\x},{\y})
       };}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```